# Quandl code is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, quandl, valueerror

I have just started using Quandl and Pandas when I came across this code.

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
api_key=open('quandlapi.txt','r').read()
df = quandl.get("FMAC/HPI_TX", authtoken=api_key)
fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')

main_df = pd.DataFrame()

for abbv in fiddy_states[0][0][1:]:
    query="FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv)

    df = quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)

    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df)
```

But when I run it I get the following error :

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Value'], dtype='object')
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing here.?

Comment: on your join - error message says you are trying to join two dfs with columns named `'Value'`, so either need to rename or use the suffix keyword to rename in the join

Comment: Hi @chrisb .. Thanks for replying..
How should I do that... Can you help me out?

Comment: I think you want to `pd.concat` not join.  You want concatenate each state to the main dataframe.  `main_df= pd.concat([main_df, df])`

Comment: Hi @ScottBoston ... _main_df= pd.concat([main_df, df])_ worked fine.. But I don't understand why the join() didn't work. Is there any way to make the join() work??

Comment: Join you would will work of you used lsuffix = '_L' and rsuffix='_R', because you have value in both dataframes you need to append something to the column to make two distinct column names.

Comment: So you mean to say that I have to change the column names of both the frames, is it???

Comment: `main_df = main_df.join(df, lsuffix='_L', rsuffix='_R')`

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston .. I will try that.... :)